# Java Collections containsAll Weired Behavior

Tags: java, list, collections, hashset

I have following code , where I am using superList and subList , I want to check that subList is actually a subList of superList.

My objects do not implement hashCode or equals methods. I have created the similar situation in the test. When I run the test then the result show very big performance difference between results from JDK collection and common collections.After Running the test I am getting following output.

Time Lapsed with Java Collection API 8953 MilliSeconds & Result is true
Time Lapsed with Commons Collection API 78 MilliSeconds & Result is true

My question is why is java collection , so slow in processing the containsAll operation. Am I doing something wrong there? I have no control over collection Types I am getting that from legacy code. I know if I use HashSet for superList then I would get big performance gains using JDK containsAll operation, but unfortunately that is not possible for me.

```
package com.mycompany.tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CollectionComparison_UnitTest {

    private Collection<MyClass> superList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    private Collection<MyClass> subList = new HashSet<MyClass>(50000);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(i + "A String");
            superList.add(myClass);
        subList.add(myClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isSubList = superList.containsAll(subList);
        System.out.println("Time Lapsed with Java Collection API "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
                + " MilliSeconds & Result is " + isSubList);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        isSubList = CollectionUtils.isSubCollection(subList, superList);
        System.out.println("Time Lapsed with Commons Collection API "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
                + " MilliSeconds & Result is " + isSubList);
    }   
}

class MyClass {
    String myString;

    MyClass(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

}
```

Comment: My guess is that commons collections takes a copy of the data rather than a view of the original data.  This could make a big difference to the performance.

Comment: This test is not good enough to be conclusive. You should have an iteration around the test to make sure it is long enough to be measuring performance and not, say, how long it takes for HotSpot to optimise your code. You should also consider running tests on one data structure at a time, i.e. a single program invocation should only use one of the data structures. This should help mitigate JIT compilation affecting your results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different algorithms:

`ArrayList.containsAll()` offers **O(N*N)**, while `CollectionUtils.isSubCollection()` offers **O(N+N+N)**.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList.containsAll` is inherited from `AbstractCollection.containsAll` and is a simple loop checking all elements in row. Each step is a slow linear search. I don't know how `CollectionUtils` works, but it's not hard to do it much faster then using the simple loop. Converting the second List to a `HashSet` is a sure win. Sorting both lists and going through them in parallel could be even better.

#### EDIT:

The [CollectionUtils source code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.java.htm) makes it clear. They're converting both collections to "cardinality maps", which is a simple and general way for many operations. In some cases it may not be a good idea, e.g., when the first list is empty or very short, you in fact loose time. In you case it's a huge win in comparison to AbstractCollection.containsAll, but you could do even better.

#### Addendum years later

The OP wrote

> I know if I use HashSet for superList then I would get big performance gains using JDK containsAll operation, but unfortunately that is not possible for me.

and that's wrong. Classes without `hashCode` and `equals` inherit them from `Object` and *can be used* with a `HashSet` and everything works perfectly. Except for that each object is unique, which may be unintended and surprising, but the OP's test `superList.containsAll(subList)` does exactly the same thing.

So the quick solutions would be

```
new HashSet<>(superList).containsAll(subList)
```

Comment: +1 for checking the source code! This answer is way more informative than the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

You should at least try the tests in the opposite order. Your results may very well just show that the JIT compiler is doing its job well :-)

Comment: When I tried with reverse order 


Time Lapsed with Commons Collection API 32 MilliSeconds & Result is true
Time Lapsed with Java Collection API 8859 MilliSeconds & Result is true

Comment: @ZoFreX
I cannot change the datat structure types , as mentioned in my problem.  I ran test within a loop in reverse order and results are consistently same , no matter how many times I loop through the code , I tried it iteratively 1 times, 20, 50 and 100 times. Results are consistent always.

Comment: You can do something like `superList.containsAll(new HashSet(subList))` and get a huge speed up.

Comment: @maaartinus yes , infact I did reverse i.e
(new HashSet(superList)).containsAll(subList)
and it gained good performance. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, your direction is the right one. Mine doesn't help at all.